# C# Remove x Number of Parent Directories from String

Tags: c#, directory

I am reading several files from a directory and inserting their path into an array of strings like so:

```
string[] file_tree = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(file_path), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Each element in the array looks like:

```
C:\\filepath1\\filepath2\\filepath3\\filepath4\\file.txt
```

I would like them to end up looking like this:

```
\\filepath3\\filepath4\\file.txt
```

Note: In my case, the names of the parent directories (`filepath1`, `filepath2`, etc) are not always the same.

What is the most efficient way to remove the top X amount of parent directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 2;
file_tree = file_tree.Select(a => string.Join("\\",a.Split('\\').Skip(x).ToArray())).ToArray();
```

**Explanation:**

`a.Split('\\')` splits the string by `\\`

`.Skip(x)` skips x element from it

`string.Join("\\", result)` joins the items in result with `\\` and produce a string

`file_tree.Select(a => ...)` for each item (a) in the array selects the new produced string

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6F7l3i)

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a little bit of an explanation so I can understand what each piece does?

Comment: Awesome, perfect!